# MySQL multiple foreign key in single table

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have the following tables:

TABLE DEVICES_ID

```
devId
dev1
dev2
dev3
```

---

TABLE USERS:

```
user  phone mail
user1 12345 1@mail.com
user2 13246 2@mail.com
user3 54321 3#mail.com
```

---

TABLE TYPES:

```
type
type1
type2
type3
type4
```

---

where DEVID, USER and TYPE are primary keys. I then want a table with unique ALARM_ID, with references to several of each of these tables:

TABLE ALARMS:

```
alarmId users        types        devices
1       user1,user2  type4,type2  dev1,dev2
2       user1,user3  type1,type3  dev2,dev3
2       user2,user3  type4,type3  dev1,dev3
```

Is this possible? meaning that each value in the ALARMS table is a reference to the value of the other tables. I know i can do this with a single value, but i need to do it with many.

Or maybe it's a poor desing for the database.

Comment: Your table ALARMS would only have one FK per column per row. Or, you could create a many to many relationship between each row in ALARMS and the other tables using a "linking" table for each. IOW, ALARMS_USERS would have a key to USERS and a key to ALARMS. Same for the other two tables. The real question is what is the relationship between the "things" in the real world. Can an alarm have multiple users? Can it have multiple types? Can it have multiple devices? I'm guessing yes to the last two, but can it have multiple types per device?

Comment: Recommendations on a linking table:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: What are the properties of each alarm? For example, on our phone, the alarm has a time, on/off, ringtone, etc. Your table Alarms should contain just  the properties of the alarm, and everything else should be linked through a linking table.

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of "references to tables" and think in terms of what a row in a table says. You are interested in alarm(alarmId, user, type, device) "alarm *alarmId* is of type *type* and involves user *user* and device *device*". Is it really the case that that the rows of that table are limited to always having to express what the rows do for table alarms(alarmId, userSetId, typeSetId, deviceSetId) "alarm *alarmId* and ... set *typeSetId* ... set *useSetId* ... set *deviceSetId*" with userSet(id, user), etc? Finally if a table is limited declare a constraint (PK, UNIQUE, FK, etc).